# Different results from Google Chrome and Internet Explorer using Google

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, internet-explorer

When I search for .NET related questions on Google Chrome using Google, it does not display results from MSDN.

When I do the same search from Internet Explorer I get results from MSDN.

I clear out all my cookies, history, etc on both browsers.

Can someone tell me why I am not seeing the same results even when I'm using the same search engine?

I'm using google.com through the US.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Google for both searches? Is one google.com and the other google.co.uk (say)?

Comment: yes. Same version of google. using google.com from US.

Comment: Odd - I get MSDN results from google.co.uk regardless of browser. Is one browser going through a proxy while the other isn't?

Comment: Both use same proxy. Now I started to think, maybe any of google chrome extensions not liking MSDN?

Comment: Could you be logged into your google account on one browser and not the other?

Answer (score 1):

**Can someone tell me why?** Because you used different web browsers.

Google, is an advertising company, a pretty big and successful one. So, it's not surprising that one component in deciding what search results are most relevant to you is what browser you're using.

From that information, they can infer generalizations about you and thus attempt to show you particularly relevant things.

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure I'm not.

Comment: I visit MSDN like 60 times a day. And why would google skip those in my search results? I

Comment: They probably assume Chrome users aren't Windows Devs - as those types are pretty inclined to use IE... At least, if I were Google, I'd be inclined to think that way.. Not to say it's perfectly correct.. Obviously..

Comment: I get MSDN results from chrome using the chrome search bar and Im I windows (web) developer